# Is it possible to set self.var123 as var123 in rest of class definition?

Tags: python, class, variables

Right now i'm doing:

```
class Block:        
    def __init__(self, lenght, height, width, position=(0,0)):

        self.lenght = lenght
        self.height= height
        self.width = width
        self.corner = tuple(position)
```

My code is about blocks, indeed.
And I also define methods for calculating the volume, surface area, etc. for that block.

My question is, when i'm writing those other methods, couldn't i shorten my code and make it easier to understand if i have `length` as the variable for `self.length`?
Is it possible to name the `lenght` once, and not at the beginning of every method?

Comment: You need to put `self.` at the start of each variable to show its scope

Comment: Note: youve spelt length wrong in your code. What is your main concern with the self?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a local reference in a method for variables you are using a lot:

```
def some_method(self):
    length = self.length
    # code that uses length
```

You can't otherwise make attributes on `self` locals, no.

Comment: So i'll have to that at the start of every method, but there's no way to it just once? Okay, thanks for the fast answer! :)

Comment: @YarrikV: no, what's what I stated in my answer already: *You can't otherwise make attributes on self locals*. And not every method will need *all* attributes.